# Android ForegorundService keeps running after app is closed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, foreground-service

I've and app made with Xamarin Forms in which I need to track location every 5 minutes even if app is in the background (not closed).

In iOS it's simple, enable location background updates and all works fine. Close app and location tracking stops.

Now with Android to be able to track location in the background you need to start ForegroundService. Everything works fine, but when I close the app (by swiping from recent apps), foreground service is still running and location is still tracked.

My question - how can I make foreground service to stop when the app is closed? I did some googling and everyone is asking exactly the opposite - how to keep foreground service running when app is closed, so I'm confused.

Comment: It's because there is no "app is closed" state ... since for `ForegorundService`  it is require to have notification you may provide a way to stop service from this notification

Comment: Thank you Selvin. Looks like I need to read more about Android. Yes, I'm using notification and you can tap on it and force stop the app, but I wonder how many users realises this. 

Our app allows techs to track their location and submit to HQ while they are on the road, but once they finish work and close the app it would be nice to stop tracking automatically somehow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328556/199364

Comment: Thanks Steve, OnTaskRemoved is what I needed!